# Can I trace Website Addresses that a Bitcoin wallet has passed through?

Tags: wallet, address

first time posting here.

Please help. I have a BTC wallet address, and I would like to know to which websites/IP addresses this BTC wallet has been used to. Something like If I use this BTC wallet address on a certain website, can it be traced?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: are you using an online wallet? Or do you have a wallet on your pc, and want to know if your tx from your pc can be traced by IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bitcoin address and private key are created locally from a random seed and because there are so many possible addresses you can be very very very much sure that it hasn't been used by anyone else.

IP adresses or websites that have used a specific bitcoin address aren't recorded in the blockchain

Hope this answers your question!